# build zeromq java binding on solaris

Tags: java, makefile, zeromq

I'm trying to build the zeromq java binding on solaris.

I've successfully installed the most recent version of 0MQ, but when i to build the java binding using make i get the following error:

Any ideas?

```
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
failcom='exit 1'; \
for f in x $MAKEFLAGS; do \
  case $f in \
    *=* | --[!k]*);; \
    *k*) failcom='fail=yes';; \
  esac; \
done; \
dot_seen=no; \
target=`echo all-recursive | sed s/-recursive//`; \
list='src perf'; for subdir in $list; do \
  echo "Making $target in $subdir"; \
  if test "$subdir" = "."; then \
    dot_seen=yes; \
    local_target="$target-am"; \
   else \
     local_target="$target"; \
  fi; \
 (cd $subdir && make  $local_target) \
 || eval $failcom; \
 done; \
 if test "$dot_seen" = "no"; then \
   make  "$target-am" || exit 1; \
 fi; test -z "$fail"
 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `all-recursive'
```